# How to safely reuse scissors used to open food packaging multiple days in a row?

Tags: food-safety, utensils

I often have to resort to prepared food from the local supermarket for a number of consecutive days because my parents are on vacation. This food is sealed in vacuum bags and usually requires 3-5 minutes in the microwave depending on the type of food. The bags need to opened using scissors after they have been heated.

Because of the limited amount of scissors in the house, I often need to resort to reusing one or more scissors for 2 or more days in a row. What precautions should I take to avoid food poisoning?

Comment: Wash scissors after each use ...

Comment: Oh my. Do you have one of those [toothbrush sterilizer](http://www.amazon.com/Germ-Terminator-GT100-Toothbrush-Sanitizer/dp/B00098198U/ref=sr_1_3?s=hpc&ie=UTF8&qid=1403543537&sr=1-3&keywords=toothbrush+sterilizer) things? If not, you need one. Get a second one for your kitchen shears.

Comment: I highly recommend 'come apart' kitchen shears -- you open them far enough (about 90 degrees from closed), and the two parts can seperate for easy cleaning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wash the scissors in hot soapy water after you've used them.

Comment: just so I understand you properly: do I need to do this after I opened each bag, or can I do this after I opened all the bags?

Comment: If the food is all cooked you should be fine to open all the bags with the same pair of scissors then wash them afterwards. You don't use a separate knife and fork for every item on the plate, after all :)

Comment: And if they're not specifically kitchen shears, make sure to dry them immediately.  (as they might not be made from stainless steel)